# htaccess redirect IE to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect MS IE6-8 to go to /ie/$1 on the same domain but I am getting a endless redirect loop, a la: mydomain.com/ie/ie/ie/ie/...
I added this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ie/,` but it did not help. Any insight?
This is my htaccess file: 
(It's an Angular app that redirects search engines to templates in the /seo folder. Just left it in here for completeness in case it makes a difference)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Angular routes pointing to the same index file
RewriteRule ^home /index.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page1 /index.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page2 /index.html [NC,L]

# IE templates
RewriteRule ^ie/(.*)$ /ie/$1_tpl.html [NC,L]

#IE redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ie/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ie/$1 [R=301,L]

#SEO redirects
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seo/%1_seo.html? [NC,L]
```